# How do I install wallpapers of 13.10 on 13.04

Tags: 13.04, 13.10, desktop-background

I am using Ubuntu 13.04(raring) and wants to install the official wallpapers of 13.10(saucy)-

I know, it can be done by downloading them from internet.

After searching a lot got

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-wallpapers-oneiric`

for installing wallpapers of 11.10 and similar commands for previous builds , but What about 13.10 , how can i install them on 13.04.

I have allready tried

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-wallpapers-saucy
```

but it did not work.it just says as below [image: like this]

Answer (score 1):

You can download `saucy` wallpapers from the Launchpad page.

**Graphically**

Through your browser visit [this page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/+source/ubuntu-wallpapers) and download the file : ubuntu-wallpapers_13.04.0+13.10.20130924.1.orig.tar.gz

Then open the file manager goto the Downloads folder and right click on the file and "extract here". A folder with the same name will be created. If you want this folder in the original wallpapers folder you will need root privileges in order to move it there. (/usr/share/backgrounds/)

**For terminal**

Open a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and execute the following commands one by one

```
wget "https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/+source/ubuntu-wallpapers/13.04.0+13.10.20130924.1-0ubuntu1/+files/ubuntu-wallpapers_13.04.0+13.10.20130924.1.orig.tar.gz"

tar xvzf ubuntu-wallpapers_13.04.0+13.10.20130924.1.orig.tar.gz

sudo mv ubuntu-wallpapers-13.04.0+13.10.20130924.1/ /usr/share/backgrounds/
```

### Alternatively

You can [locate](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/ubuntu-wallpapers-saucy_13.04.0%2B13.10.20130924.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb) and download the .deb package for an easy installation. The installation process it will install the wallpapers at the right directory.

```
wget "https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/ubuntu-wallpapers-saucy_13.04.0%2B13.10.20130924.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb" 
sudo dpkg -i ubuntu-wallpapers-saucy_13.04.0%2B13.10.20130924.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb
```

Comment: yeah it will do the work , but its the same as downloading it from internet , and manually moving those files in background through terminal, why "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-wallpapers-saucy" dont work.

Comment: it moved the files  as you mentioned but i am not getting any of them in "change desktop background"

Comment: Have tried to install them with the alternative way ? (through the .deb package). I think you should move the files as files and not as an entire folder in order to see them in "change desktop background"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-wallpapers-saucy
```

I got it from [here](http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/saucy/main/u/ubuntu-wallpapers-saucy/install.html)

Comment: it says "E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-wallpapers-saucy"

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kwwii/ppa` Do this before that.

Comment: still same error..

Comment: Why don't you download the images and set it up as background?

Comment: i know i can do it , but as it was used before to install , why cant we use that method now. whats changed in that ? or there could be some blockage in repo.

Comment: As for I know in ubuntu repos changes more frequently so as to ensure Open source GPL. It might have removed for that reason.